# What is the purpose and how this SQL query functions?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have unfortunately executed this query and my website is not displaying some values properly from SQL database now. Could anyone explain what this query actually do?

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = CAST(REPLICATE(N'A',3000) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE(N'B',3000) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
SELECT LEN(@SQL)
```

Comment: That query has *no* side effects. If things are now broken, it's not related to this query.

Comment: Thank you Damien_The_Unbeliever!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's break your code:

```
-- string variable declaration @SQL at this moment it is NULL
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- assign to variable @SQL concatentation of AAA...AAABBB...BBB
--                                           3000     3000
SET @SQL = CAST(REPLICATE(N'A',3000) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(REPLICATE(N'B',3000) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))

--get length of string (6000 = 3000 + 3000)
SELECT LEN(@SQL)
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cd867bcae05ff617efbe11ec669a9bdc)**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Lukasz Szozda!